# る form and おう form of verbs when used with と思う

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between these 2 sentences:

> 買ってくると思った 
>   買ってこようと思った

Both of them translates to 'I thought that I'd go and buy'

Answer (score -1):

買ってくると思った。　I understood that someone went shopping and I thought he would buy it but He didn't.

買ってこようと思った。  'I thought that I'd go and buy'
　For example.
買ってこようと思ったのに、忘れた。　I thought that I'd go and buy、 but I forgot about it. 
その話を聞いて、今度買ってこようと思った。 After I had the conversation, I decided to buy it.

Comment: The way you've written it it sounds like the difference is between third person and first person usage. That isn't correct.

Comment: ^ `That isn't correct.` <- Oh? But if we native speakers heard you say 買ってくると思った out of the blue, we'd interpret it as "I thought **you/s/he/someone** would go and buy", and if we heard 買ってこようと思った out of the blue, we'd interpret it as "I was going to / I thought **I** would go and buy."

Comment: Really? I think I have heard hear native speakers saying this form regarding their own actions.

Comment: ^ 動詞によるような気がしますね。例えば「８時ごろに帰ると思う」って言ったら "I think I'll come back..." でも "I think s/he will come back..." でもありえますし。（「8時ごろに帰ろうと思う」だったら "I will try to..." みたいな感じ）

Comment: @Ben You can apply it to your own action in subjunctive. However, you can't use it to express your intention.

Comment: The "but he didn't" part, is that always implied? In other words saying 買ってくると思った has exactly the same meaning as 買ってくると思ったが買わなかった? Also, if I wanted to say "I thought he went and bought it but I am not sure if he did actually buy it", leaving the sentence as 買ってくると思った would be wrong? And it has to be somewhere along the lines of 買ってくると思ったが買ったかどうかわからんわ？